# Basic question about postgresql configuration

Tags: linux, postgresql, service

I just installed the new version of Elementary OS and I lost the configuration that makes work my Postgresql.

I have an app that works perfectly online with a remote DB on Heroku, but when I run that on my local machine I can't reach the server. I think I miss something in the pg_hba.conf because I have all services up and running and all ports open for the DB. Actually I have this config file

```
    # Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 md5
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
host    all             all             ::/0                    md5
```

I hope you can give me a way to contact my DB. In the last installation, I was able to, but I lost the config file.

Comment: Did you read the [documentation of PostGreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/)? Please cite in your question the things you don't understand there and provide some [mre]. Maybe use [strace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) to understand what is happening

Comment: Consider also using [proc(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) to understand what is going on your Linux system

Comment: Next time use [git](http://git-scm.com/) on your configuration files, and backup them. They are as important as the PostGreSQL data

Comment: What is the error you get when you try to connect?

Answer (score 0):

Hello and thanks for the replies. I read the docs that says just how to connect to local service or configure a server that runs on a machine. I did all the steps before (just in case): user add, configuration of the local DB, giving admin user to the DB etc.

This line (the last)

```
host    all             all             ::/0                    md5
```

Is the one the docs say to add, but it is working for DB calls on the same machine.

I take web monitors, scanned ports and whatever I could see on linux system: ports for Postgresql are open, service runs, seems all fine. DB is reachable via PGAdmin, same credentials in the app. App is a NodeJS that calls the DB for an interactive website.
For those reasons I believe that should be a configuration problem. I have also no active firewall, no other rules than the actual config file for postgresql.

As I write the app works perfectly when it is on local or when it is all on the server. I need to have a cross config for development to have  quick way to work on the actual online DB and a local copy (editable) of the web app. Or permit more people to develop at same time from different machines.

There is no error, just the app can't go online to get the DB and loops to find it. At last goes timeout.
Last time I had fix this with a similar line, obviously it is not the right form. What I ask is simply a line of config. I am not skilled in server configuration and I don't need to be anyway: once this will be online the server will have already configuration. I don't even care on what SQL type I will work, the app has a parser that makes all SQLs compatible.

I had to restore the system because of a problem, otherwise all was working before and I changed just that line, can't remember how...

Hope this will clear the situation.